# Problema con URIBuilder y parametro con ","

Tags: java, url, uri

Estoy desarrollando mi aplicación la creación de una URL a través de URIBuilder.

De momento todo perfecto hasta que me he encontrado que me llega un parametro tal que así "02025,02024", bien, ahora mismo lo tengo hecho de esta manera:

```
    public static URIBuilder addVariableUrl(URIBuilder url, String name, String value) {
    return url.setParameter(name, value);
}
```

De esta forma, cuando me llega un parámetro, lo añado a la URL correctamente... pero si me llega el parámetro anteriormente dicho, la URL que me forma es esta

"URL_FORMADA"?**eess=02025%2C+02024** (eess es el name), como podéis ver no sabe interpretar el carácter "," y lo pone con %2C" (en Hexadecimal)

Por tanto, cuando llamo a la URL, la esta mandando con los caracteres en Hexadecimal y da error.

¿Sabéis como adaptar URIBuilder para que coja bien el carácter de ","?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si lo que quieres es una uri para el restTemplate, con una string vale, para el tema de las , yo jamás he visto una url formada por comas... usa alguna transformación que solo conozcas tú, en plan " si aparece coma cámbialo por " #!--" y desde el otro lado que compruebe que si ha venido eso, se sustituya por una coma.

Comment: Buenas Edu, el tema de las comas, es porque al servicio al que llamo lo tienen así adaptado, ya que es una busqueda en BBDD por tanto cuando yo le envío "1414,1415", lo que hace el servicio es meterlo en una query suya "where XX in (1414,1415)", por eso se le pasan las comas...

Luego he planteado añadir lo que dices, si la url tiene el formato hexadecimal, sustituirlo directamente por una coma, pero es algo jaleo y pensaba que quizas el URIBuilder tiene algo propio para que las comas no las convierta en hexadecimal

Comment: ¿ Y si lo envías por post ? algunos carácteres enviados por url (get), van a ser transformados, pero, si lo envías por post, van a conservar la consistencia de los datos.

Comment: No puedo  enviarlo por post, ya que el servicio al que estoy llamando está preparado para recibirlo como get, es inviable modificarlo...

Comment: Como bien ya te contestaron, la coma es un carácter reservado y como buena practica el receptor no debiera de recibir el carácter en al URL sino su contratarte es la idea de Utilizar URIBuilder y cualquier otra librería HTTP, también si quieres mantener el Tipo URL o URI puedes utilizar `URL url = new URL(URLDecoder.decode(uriBuilder.build().toString(), "UTF-8"));` y `url.toURI()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La coma tiene [un significado especial en una URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3), es un carácter reservado y ha de ser escapado cuando quieres mandarlo como parte de la información, al igual que el espacio. Por ejemplo:

```js
let urlParcial ='02025,02024';
let codificado=encodeURIComponent(urlParcial);
console.log(codificado);
console.log(decodeURIComponent(codificado));
```

Del mismo modo tienes que tratar el valor en Java, decodificando los valores. Generalmente los frameworks que gestionan las peticiones vía HTTP (como Spring, por ejemplo), suelen gestionar esta transformación automáticamente, pero en caso de necesidad puedes hacerlo manualmente así:

```
String datos = URLDecoder.decode(url,"UTF-8");
```

usando la clase [URLDecoder de Java SE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))

Dicho de otro modo: tu URIBuilder transforma el parámetro de la forma correcta, pero es el servidor el que no está haciendo la transformación inversa correctamente. Una URL con comas puede darte problemas

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo!, ahora sí, con el decode me transforma el hexadecimal a ",".

Con esto me vale, muchisimas gracias!